# Looking for suggestions: tools to create an online catalogue?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla

Ok, so my problem is that i'm creating an antiques directory and i need some help in reccomedding the tools i'll need to do the job. I'm ok with programming but fairly basic.

I want a user to  be able to search my website for a phrase or choose a category and then return images of the antiques that they entered in my directory.

What things should i be looking at to do this? i.e. wordpress/drupal/joomla and if so what plugins would i need?! Can anyone help?

Thankyou =] 
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

If you have the patience to learn Drupal & CCK+Views you would have everything you need in a well customizable package, and most likely it could be done with no programming at all, just configuration.

The way you would do it in Drupal is to create a new content type for your antiques, and attach various fields (image, text, this, that, whatever) using the CCK (Content Construction Kit) Module and it's sub modules. Then you would assign taxonomy terms (categories) to individual Antiques when added.

Finally you would create a View or 2 using the Views module and a few views sub modules to filter on taxonomy term categories (using say autocomplete) and then return said catalog however you please...

check it all out at [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org)

Drupal loves you

Comment: @gaurav - Thanks very much guys! i will get onto this straight away and let you know how things go =]